# Ruby on rails button that will not redirect to another page but does it's action on the same view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, button, view

before anyone get's mad I would like to start by apologizing by how stupid it may seem to some but i'm really having a hard time finding out how.

I have been looking through tutorials online on how to program in ruby on rails but I can't seem to find out how to make a button that does it's action and won't redirect to another page. For example when I want my program to count the number of people present in my database I need to make another view where the action would be executed. I would like to make it do the action on the same view and not redirect to another page.
Every tutorial that I've gone through only redirects the action to another page.
Could anyone please help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should use AJAX.

Comment: Don't apologise for feeling stupid. We're all in that boat sometimes.

Comment: @joshua.paling : Thank you for commenting that. I'll try to keep that in mind :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose that you want to have that button in an `index` page of some controller. If you add something like this (I'm using [HAML](http://haml.info/) here):

```
= link_to "Something"
```

Then clicking the link will refresh the page *but* calling the `index` method of your controller again before rendering. Now the only problem is to figure out if the `index` method has been called by clicking on the `Something` link or just by calling the page? You can do this by passing some parameters (e.g. `?mylink=true`) when clicking the link.

**HOWEVER** I personally prefer to implement a custom controller method (via `routes.rb`) and then redirect to the desired page (e.g. `index`). Something like this:

**`routes.rb`**

```rb
resource :my_resource
  collection do
    get "test"
  end
end
```

**`my_resource_controller.rb`**

```rb
...

def test
  # Do stuff
  redirect_to action: "index
end
```

**`my_resource/index.html.haml`**

```
= link_to "Something", text_my_resource_path
```

Now clicking on `Something` link gets you to `test` method and after doing your stuff you are redirected back to where you were (i.e. `index`). Read more about `redirect_to` [HERE](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Redirecting.html#method-i-redirect_to).

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time and effort to answer my question :).

Comment: @jin if it helped you  with your problem, you can mark it as the correct answer :)

Comment: I really appreciate the effort and everything, it helped me understand redirect_to better but i'm sorry but I believe you read my title wrong :c. What I am looking for is how to make a button that will do it's action "without" redirecting. I would like to to vote it up but it requires 15 reputation.

Comment: I read it right. It is however impossible to do that if you are not using Ajax. If you're doing it the good old HTML way, you need to make a call to the server and wait for it to make a response. If you don't want a "redirect" how should server know if you have refreshed the button or clicked on the button?